# Is HttpClient async safe?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I suddenly got some doubts on this. HttpClient is thread safe according to MSDN (for GetAsync or PostAsync at least).

But if I do this

```
List<Task> tasks= new List<Task>(); 
tasks.Add(_httpClient.PostAsync(url1, requestMessage1));
tasks.Add(_httpClient.PostAsync(url2, requestMessage2));
Tasks.Wait(tasks);
```

Will I get correct results back all the time as both calls come from the same thread now?

Comment: Since it is thread safe I dont see any problem with that code. But I'm not sure I understand what you mean by your last sentence. "Same thread"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will I get correct results back all the time as both calls come from the same thread now?

Yes.  That's the indented usage of HttpClient.

"An HttpClient instance is a collection of settings applied to all requests executed by that instance. In addition, every HttpClient instance uses its own connection pool"

[HttpClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8)